# Vector2 keeps setting my float to negative

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I have a float like this

```
float value = 200;
```

And I want to set the `Top` value of a `RectTransform`.

```
RectTransform rect = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
Vector2 newSize = new Vector2(rect.offsetMax.x, value);
rect.offsetMax = newSize;
```

I don't know why but it sets the `rect.offsetMax.y` to `-200`. I already tried:

```
float positivevalue = Math.Abs(value);
Vector2 newSize = new Vector2(rect.offsetMax.x, positivevalue );
```

It's still negative. If I print the values:

```
print(rect.offsetMax.y); // this returns 200 and not -200
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE: ACTUAL CODE**

```
float y = Math.Abs(25f);
rect.offsetMax = new Vector2(rect.offsetMax.x, y);
print($"Y: {y}, Rect Transform: {rect.offsetMax.y}");
```

Comment: Does it return `-300` for `300`? Is it really inverting the sign of the value that's set? Can you try printing `rect.offsetMax.x` and check if it is the same as displayed in the hierarchy?

Comment: I dont know about unity3d, but you are setting the value of `value` variable. and not setting the property of `rect`, but of `newSize `

Comment: To start with, `value` is a reserved word. What you've posted won't compile. Try sharing the actual code.

Comment: @viveknuna yes because I cannot change the `rect.offsetMax.y` directly. I need to change it as a Vector2

Comment: `It's still negative. If I print the values:

print(rect.offsetMax.y); // this returns 200 and not -200` ... so it is behaving as expected? ^^ You might want to rephrase this or explain further what value exactly is showing `-200`

Answer (score -1):

I manage to solve it by turning my `value` to negative then assigned it to the new vector:

```
float newvalue = -value;
```

Comment: this looks more like a workaround than a fix to me